# Show NuGet package release notes

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuspec

The [nuspec reference](http://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference) says about the releaseNotes tag

> v1.5 A description of the changes made in each release of the package. This field only shows up when the *Updates* tab is selected and the package is an update to a previously installed package. It is displayed where the Description would normally be displayed.

I created two nuspec files, both containing (with different `version` tags of course)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>TestReleaseNotes</id>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <authors>adrianm</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Release notes</releaseNotes>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="Test.cs" target="content" />
  </files>
</package>
```

I installed 1.0 in VS2013 and selected the update tab but I can't see the release notes.
[image: Nuget update]

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems OK for me with VS 2013 and an old version of Microsoft.ApplicationInsights installed the NuGet dialog shows a separate Release Notes label with the release note text from the NuGet package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found this out myself.

The release notes are displayed if I open the "Manage NuGet packages" dialog from the `project`.
[image: manage from project]
but not when I open it from the `solution`.

The behaviour is the same for my own packages as well as nuget.org

Comment: I'm on Visual Studio 2015 with NuGet 3.3. It seems no matter how I open it: 1) Manage NuGet Packages... (for the project), or 2) Manage NuGet Packages for the Solution..., I don't see release notes. I've spent more time trying to track down release notes for updates so that any productivity benefit I'm getting form NuGet seems to be lost!
For example, I'm currently trying to see the release notes for Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.0.0.0 and I can see is the Description!
Anyone find a way to see the release notes in VS 2015?

Comment: It's 2020, still not available in VS 2019

Comment: Is is unbelievable that such an important feature for package manager is not available/broken for so long :/

Answer (score 7):

This still seems to be an issue in Visual Studio 2019 as at March 2021.
We publish a number of nuget packages internally using Azure. The Package Release Notes show up in the Azure UI but not in Visual Studio. However, the "Description" does show up in Visual Studio, so I've tweaked the Description to include the release notes. This is actually from the Directory.build.props file, but could equally well be embedded in the project file:

```xml
        <PackageReleaseNotes>
Release notes added to .nuspec file as <Release Notes> and also to end of Description
        </PackageReleaseNotes>
        <!-- Don't indent text, it makes it hard to read in the nuget package manager-->
        <Description>
Description:
This is the description of our internally produced nuget package

Release Notes:$(PackageReleaseNotes)
        </Description>
```

Comment: But as soon as you edit the description the first time through the GUI (VS2019/VS2022) the placeholder `$(PackageReleaseNotes)` is gone as the expanded text is saved.

Answer (score 5):

This issue is tracked in the NuGet repo regarding VS2015.

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1823

Comment: This is still not available on VS2022.